# Cdf of minimum of two iid random variables

Tags: random-variable, cumulative-distribution-function, extreme-value

I am struggling with the following sentence:

> Using the fact that the cumulative distribution of the
>   minimum of two i.i.d. random variables can be expressed as $1 - (1 - F(x))^2$....

Can anyone show me why this is the case?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's a common trick. If $X = \min(Y_1,Y_2)$ and $F$, $F_X$ are the CDFs of the $Y_i$s and $X$, respectively, then 
\begin{align*}
F_X(x) &= 1 - P(X > x) \\
&= 1- P(Y_1 > x, Y_2 > x) \\
&= 1 - P(Y_1 > x)P(Y_2 > x) \text{ independence}\\
&= 1 - [1-F(x)][1-F(x)] \text{ identicalness}.
\end{align*}

Comment: :-) well that's easier than I thought. Thank you!

Comment: +1 for the answer, but why do you call it a "trick"?