# Smallest gap between $n$ Poisson events

Tags: distributions, poisson-process

Given a Poisson process with parameter $\lambda,$ run time forward until the first $n>1$ events occur. What is the distribution of the smallest time interval between two events?

This is surely standard (and probably related to Erlang) but I can't find anything, can anyone help?

I'm especially interested in addressing questions of the flavor, "I have $n$ events in $t$ time and no reason to think anything funny is going on, except that two events are as close as $y$. How unlikely would this be in a Poisson process with $\lambda = t/n$?". Suggestions, comments, objections, etc. to this methodology would be appreciated (in a comment, unless you're also answering the question).

Comment: I think you may be looking for the exponential distribution:  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution

Comment: Minimum order statistics of a sample of exponential random variables?

Comment: Let $T_i$ be the interarrival times, are you interested in finding the distribution of $T=\min (T_1,...,T_n)$ or $T|\sum_{i=1}^n T_i < t$?

Answer (score 3):

As I mention [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/325539/lambda-exponential-vs-poisson-interpretation/325544#325544), the interarrival times $T_1, T_2, \ldots$ are distributed as $\text{Exponential}(\lambda)$ random variables. You seem to be interested in $T=\min (T_1,...,T_n)$ somehow, but as @gunes points out, you aren't clear about whether or not you're assuming that the total amount of time to get $n$ events must be less than $t$: "I have $n$ events in $t$ time." You need to tell us whether $t$ is random or not.

If it is, ot's more conventional to use uppercase letters, however capital $T$ is already taken to mean the minimum of all the interarrival times. The distribution of the minimum can easily be found [using the following technique](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/321446/cdf-of-minimum-of-two-iid-random-variables/321447#321447). [Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/220/how-is-the-minimum-of-a-set-of-random-variables-distributed) is another link addressing the same issue.

If you are constraining the total amount of time, and conditioning on the fact that it's less than $t$, you are looking for the distribution of $T|\sum_{i=1}^n T_i < t$ as [@gunes](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/204068/gunes) points out. The quickest way for me to find the cdf of this distribution is to use the Monte Carlo technique. To do this simulate $M$ sets of $n$ random variables $T_i^j$, and compute

\begin{align*}
P\left(T \le s \bigg\rvert \sum_{i=1}^n T_i < t\right) &= P\left(T \le s , \sum_{i=1}^n T_i < t\right)\bigg/ P\left(\sum_{i=1}^n T_i < t\right)\\
&\overset{\text{p}}{\leftarrow} \left(M^{-1}\sum_{j=1}^M 1\left\{T^j \le s , \sum_{i=1}^n T^j_i < t \right\}\right) \\
&\hspace{10mm} \bigg/ \left(M^{-1}\sum_{j=1}^M 1\left\{ \sum_{i=1}^n T^j_i < t .\right\}\right)\end{align*}

Here's some `R` code:

```
lambda <- 3
s <- .03
t <- 20
M <- 1000
n <- 20
samps <- matrix(rexp(M*n, lambda), nrow=M)
sum(apply(samps, 1, function(row) (min(row) < s) & (sum(row)< t)  )) / sum(apply(samps, 1, function(row) (sum(row)< t)))
```

The Erlang distribution arises as the sum of iid exponential random variables. Instead of estimating $P\left(\sum_{i=1}^n T_i < t\right)$ with samples, you could swap in the known cdf function here, and it would reduce the variance of the above Monte Carlo estimator.